# want to return an rs.getInt() value in my database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing

I want to return an `rs.getInt()` value in this code snippet in my database. I really need it because I have to display the "User's score" in my Java Swing Simple Quiz Program, but it will always return 0 instead of what I want.

```
public int score() {
    kon = koneksi.koneksiDb();

    try {
        st = kon.createStatement();
        formLogin fl = new formLogin();
        String sql = "SELECT score FROM user WHERE username = '" + fl.usr + "'";
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        if (rs.next()) 
            return rs.getInt(5);

    } catch(SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Maaf, terjadi kesalahan.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My "score" column in the database is an integer.

Comment: Two possibilities I see. The first is that you have no results. The second possibility is that you get the `SQLException` you catch. `rs.getInt(5)` will get an integer from the fifth column in your resultset but your query only has one requested column. This call will never work.

Comment: Try something like `return rs.getInt("score");` or `return rs.getInt(1);`

Comment: And also test that your query will actually return at least one row.

Comment: as @DanielBarbarian said, test your query if . i dont see anything wrong with your code. Perhaps , you would want to approach preparedStatement as its a good practice and its faster for precompiled SQL statement

Comment: Sorry i haven't checked this thread for a while. Thanks for the solutions. It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DanielBarbardian and @deHaar in the comments. I tried `return rs.getInt("score");` and it works. It'll return the score from the right column and display the right user's score.